# What's the difference between 'ionic cordova build browser' and 'ng build'?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm building a hybrid web app. It's an Angular app in an Ionic Cordova Framework.

The business that started building this app, has documented to use `ionic cordova build browser` to build the app for browser.

Now I found that this gives me some problems with splashscreens and my browser asking for permissions. I also found that using `ng build`, there is no splash screen and my browser doesn't ask for permissions.

This makes I want to build with `ng build`, at least for browser, but I'm wondering if there's problems going to occur with, for example, those permissions the angular build doesn't ask for.

My `after_build.js`, calls the following plugins:

```
const plugins = [
    'cordova-plugin-file',
    'cordova-plugin-file-opener2',
    'cordova-plugin-splashscreen',
    'cordova-plugin-android-permissions',
    'cordova-plugin-browsertab',
];
```

**Edit:**

I now see `Ionic build` uses `ng build`, but adds the ionic functionalities. (https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/build). So my only question left is, does `ionic cordova build browser` do extra things in according to permissions?

Answer (score 1):

- `ionic build` generates 2 slightly different production environments
  and only one of them seems to correctly load native Cordova device
  plugins. If someone of Ionic Team read this, perhaps can give us a
  reason...
- `ng build` I notice that Angular 2/4 is further along in their production build process. I wonder if  `ng build -- prod`is where the Ionic team is
  trying to go, and if you can use that to build the ionic project as
  well somehow.

Angular has a benefit of changing includes on index.html to have random numbers on the end, forcing user browsers to refresh files like `main.js` which is critical.